# aapt: error in executable

Tags: android-studio, aapt, aapt2

I just installed android-studio on my kubuntu 17.10 pc.
After creating a new project, android-studio tries to sync it and gradle shows the following error.
[Error-Log](https://gist.github.com/promasu/9b6c08b893b4f3ed3149a030d1f6564b)
I found already some answers here but they didn't work out.
I ran gradle as root, reinstalled android studio, removed the gradle cache folder, reinstalled the sdk, downloaded the sdk from the google page etc.

I can provide more information if you need some.

Update: I tested to execute aapt2 by hand with `aapt2 m` and got the `error in format of executable`

Kind regards

Comment: Did you find the solution that worked?

Comment: No i didn't. I now have a x64 PC and everything works